# Hbase Clone Snapshot Procedure stuck

Tags: hbase

I exported a hbase snapshot from one cluster to another.  When I tried to clone it using hbase shell it was taking much longer than expected so I looked in the log and found & fixed a permissions error.

Now I'm seeing "failed because a clone should not have regions to restore".  It's looping on this error, processing the same regions over and over (as best as I can tell).

It's been running for twenty one.  How long is it going to run?  What's the configuration option that controls that time?  My understanding is that I can't abort the procedure, is that correct?

Comment: The procedure ran for more than a day.  But when we cycled hbase the procedure restarted and completed sucessfully.

Comment: by cycled you mean? We are facing similar issue. What was the size of your snapshot

Comment: By cycled I meant stopping and restarting the cluster.  The snapshots weren't very large.  In the few hundred gigabytes to one terabyte range.

Comment: for us it got resolved by fixing permissions of entire `/apps/hbase/data/` folder using `hdfs dfs -chown -R hbase:hdfs /apps/hbase/data/`